# Prompt multiple choices to user

Tags: r, prompt

I have a data frame with scenarios

```
number  var1  var2
  1     "a1"  "b1"
  2     "a1"  "b2"
  3     "a2"  "b1"
  4     "a2"  "b2"
```

I would like to find the scenario number by asking a user the value they want for

```
var1 / var2
```

I do not think it can work with

```
readlines
```

which asks for the user to write something.

I would like something like

```
"What value of var1?"
1. "a1"
2. "a2"
```

And the users simply has to choose 1 or 2. Is that difficult?

Comment: Start with something like `x <- as.numeric(readline('What value of var1? \n 1. "a1" \n 2. "a2" \n'))`.

Comment: I guess for my use, that's enough! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a little Shiny app in R. Have a look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/ for some examples

Here is an example of a dropdown box.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput(
      "select", 
      label = h3("Select box"), 
      choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
      selected = 1
    ),
    hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))
  )
  server = function(input, output) {
    # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })
  }
)
```

Comment: I used the other and simpler suggestion for my modest needs, but will remember to take a look into this. Thanks

Comment: I aggree that it is a bit more work. But you  get a more user friendly environment. Much will depend on how R savvy the end users are.